How to get public key from private key in tact?
I have a smart contract written on tact language for TON blockchain.
I have a method that accepts private key and returns public key based on input:
get fun get_public_key_from_private_key(private_key: String): String {
    // need to do smth to get public key
    let public_key: String = private_key;

    return public_key;
}

But I haven't found any library for tact to do so. Is there any simple way to implement it?
UPD: I've found a TonoxDeFi/open-contracts library that allows me to get public key from private but via funC. Currently working on how to import funC function from the library to tact smart contract

You can’t. If this was possible, PKI would be pointless in its entirety.

@user207421 Huh? Why is that? Getting a public key from a private key is usually possible. The other way around is of course a no-go for a secure algorithm. Quite often ECDSA is used for block chain where the public key is the base point G multiplied with the "seed" that makes up the private key.

Could you instead perform cryptographic operations off-chain using tools or libraries in languages that support such operations (e.g., Python, JavaScript), and then pass the necessary data to the smart contract?

@VonC unfortunately I can't, I need to get public key on-chain
